# Problem loading Configuration

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

I try to load a System.Configuration.Configuration from a configuration-File that is stored on another location (other disk). But iam getting the following...

Exception:
An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for SectionName: Could not load file or assembly 'Assembly' or one of its dependencies.

```
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\fancyFile.xml", FileMode.CreateNew);
            fileStream.Write(MyProject.Resources.Resource, 0, MyProject.Resources.Resource.Length);
            fileStream.Close();

            System.Configuration.ConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap(@"c:\fancyFile.xml");
            MyProject.Configuration conf = MyProject.Configuration.GetConfiguration(@"c:\fancyFile.xml").GetSection("MySection") as MyProject.Configuration;

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
          <section name="MySection" type="MyProject.Configuration, MyProject" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere"  />
      </configSections>
<MySection>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only conjecture that the configuration file you're trying to load has a `/configuration/configSections/section` with a `@type` attribute which references some assembly which is not in your application bin folder.

Comment: But i try to load that in the same assmebly. Ive updated my question with more source. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though the configuration specifies an assembly name of 'Assembly'. This is probably not correct. It would be helpful if you could post the contents of the `c:\fancyFile.xml` file so that we can check this.

Comment: Ive changed the question. Now there is some content from the xml file. Thank you!